# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation with csv export related php script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm customizing a csv export php script which I admit I took from the internet but

I'm having this error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\',\' optionally enclosed by \'\'' at line 1

The line of code described is

```
$fnam2 = 'data-' . substr(md5(microtime()), 0, 8); 
$setsu->query("SELECT * FROM ".$tblname." into outfile '".$fnam2 ."' fields terminated by \',\' optionally enclosed by \'\'");
```

Which was originally

```
$setsu->query("SELECT * FROM ".$tblname.". ' into outfile "c:/xampp/htdocs/' . $fnam2 . '" fields terminated by \',\' optionally enclosed by \'"\'');
```

I would like the remove the part where it points to xampp folder so that the user can place wherever she/he wants to download the file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fnam2 = 'data-' . substr(md5(microtime()), 0, 8); 
$setsu->query("SELECT * FROM ".$tblname." into outfile '".$fnam2 ."' fields terminated by \",\" optionally enclosed by '\"'");
```

Maybe?